# Can I update index.html after start the Angular universal server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, handlebars.js, angular-universal

I have requirement to convert a server-side rendering project to client-side render, but I have to generate/render **header** html from existing tech. My plan to render header part using node-express and attach to index.html in each server hit. Once server start, I am able to render header html and update the index.html with new html string. But it will work in first hit, from second hit updated index.html not being displayed in browser.

**Existing tech stack:** 
Express, Handlebars

**New tech stack:**
Angular universal

> Note: index.html is the build file using angular universal

**server.ts**

```
// -- code --

const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('node-html-parser').parse;

var hbs = exphbs.create({
  extname: '.hbs'
}); 

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  hbs.render('./dist/server/header.hbs',{header:dynamicData}).then(headerHTML => {
    fs.readFile('./dist/browser/index.html', 'utf8' ,function(err, data) {
        const root = parse(data);
        const body = root.querySelector('header');
        body.appendChild(headerHTML+Math.random()); // add a random number for testing
        fs.writeFile("./dist/browser/index.html",root.toString(), function(err) {
          res.render('index', { req });
        });
    });
  });
});

// -- code --
```

**cmd >> npm run build:ssr** 
**cmd >> npm run serve:ssr**

Comment: If you're okay with using `pugjs` I would recommend instead of re-writing the file, you can have an express route for `./dist/browser/index.html` with a `pug` template and import the header template in it.

Comment: Hi Stephen. In my case, header is not a template. It is pure html string that pre-render using handlebars.

Comment: I haven't tried Angular universal, but I think it could be that ssr caches the index.html in some way. I'm sorry, I cannot be of much help here...